# Как работает функция fread() в PHP?

Tags: php, unicode, ascii

Привет.

Вопрос по функции `fread()` в `PHP`. Вторым аргументом в нее передается число байт, которые надо прочитать в файле.

В качестве примера я написал в файле `data.txt` текст `1Hello`, задал кодировку **`UCS-2`**. Если в редакторе шестнадцатиричном посмотреть на этот файл, то увижу это 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще написал скрипт в файле `1.php` с кодировкой `UTF-8`, который читает из файла по ОДНОМУ байту.

```
<?php 
        $q=fopen("data.txt","r");
        for($i=1;$i<=filesize("data.txt");$i=$i+1){
            echo "$i: ".fread($q,1);
            echo "<br/>";
        }
    ?>
```

Вывело это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я специально задал кодировку двухбайтвую, чтобы посмотреть, а что же мне выведет, если попасть в "середину" кодировки порядкового номера символа функцией fopen. **Мне не понятно, что мне вывело. В какой кодировке это вывелось?** **Что это за точки между буквами вставились?** Их видно на картинке.

Answer (score 1):

Функция [fread()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fread.php) читает данные **побайтно**. Тут

```
fread($q,1)
```

вы считываете каждый раз **1 байт** и выводите его на экран.

> В какой кодировке это вывелось?

Вывод у вас шел в кодировке [ISO 8859-9](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-9) или [Windows-1254](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1254) судя по первым двум символам с кодами xFE и xFF (Вы турецкий шпиён? :))

> Что это за точки между буквами вставились?

Это байты, которые не имеют соответствия в отображаемых символах той кодировке с которой работает программа. На первой вашей картинке программа поддерживает отображение только символов с кодами от x20 до x7F (остальное отобразилось точками). На второй картинке пустыми местами отображены символы с кодом x00.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, поставил плюс. то, что функция fread() читает столько байт, сколько нужно (указывается во втором параметре) - это я знаю. каждый раз я читал по одному байту и курсор перемещался на один байт. это я тоже знаю. я специально выставил в файле data.txt кодировку двухбайтную UCS-2 для того, чтобы попадать в "середину" символа и получить какую-то чепуху при выводе. хочется понимать, почему я получил именно то, что вывело. первые два байта - это BOM. вывелись они не в турецкой расширенной кодировке 1254, я смотрел - там символы другие для  xFE и xFF

Comment: @Dimon, если не верите, что браузер определил кодировку как Турецкую, откройте в браузере меню Вид - Кодировка текста (или аналогичное) и посмотрите что там выбрано при отображении страницы со второго рисунка.

Comment: действительно, кодировка турецкая. не понятно, почему она выставилась автоматически

Answer (score 1):

Что здесь действительно непонятно, так это какое отношение вопрос имеет к РНР и функции fread.

> Мне не понятно, что мне вывело.

Отдельные байты.

> В какой кодировке это вывелось?

НИ В КАКОЙ. Байты не имеют кодировки. Браузер отображает символ (если может), двоичный код которого был ему передан. С учетом кодировки, заданной в НТТР заголовке.

> Что это за точки между буквами вставились?

Это именно то, на что ты хотел посмотреть: та самая "чепуха", "если попасть в в "середину" символа". То есть ты получил ровно то что хотел, но все равно недоволен.

Точкой хекс-редактор отображает нулевой байт, чтобы не путать его с пробелом.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. плюсанул. отдельные байты вывелись в какой-то кодировке. вопрос в том, в какой кодировке они вывелись. точки эти видны только в hex-редакторе. в браузере в исходном коде видны просто пустые промежутки (как пробелы)

Comment: Ответ надо не плюсовать, а читать. в нем все написано